# Integer vs double arithmetic performance?

Tags: c#, performance, integer, double

i'm writing a C# class to perform 2D separable convolution using integers to obtain better performance than double counterpart. The problem is that i don't obtain a real performance gain.

This is the X filter code (it is valid both for int and double cases):

```
foreach (pixel)
{
      int value = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < filterOffsetsX.Length; k++)
      {
          value += InputImage[index + filterOffsetsX[k]] * filterValuesX[k];  //index is relative to current pixel position
      }
      tempImage[index] = value;
 }
```

In the integer case "value", "InputImage" and "tempImage" are of "int", "Image`<byte>`" and "Image`<int>`" types.
In the double case "value", "InputImage" and "tempImage" are of "double", "Image`<double>`" and "Image`<double>`" types.
(filterValues is int[] in each case)
(The class Image`<T>` is part of an extern dll. It should be similar to .NET Drawing Image class..).

My goal is to achieve fast perfomance thanks to int += (byte * int) vs double += (double * int)

The following times are mean of 200 repetitions.
Filter size 9  =  0.031 (double)    0.027 (int)
Filter size 13  = 0.042 (double)    0.038 (int)
Filter size 25  = 0.078  (double)   0.070  (int)

The performance gain is minimal. Can this be caused by pipeline stall and suboptimal code?

EDIT: simplified the code deleting unimportant vars.

EDIT2: i don't think i have a cache miss related problema because "index"iterate through adjacent memory cells (row after row fashion). Moreover "filterOffstetsX" contains only small offsets relatives to pixels on the same row and at a max distance of filter size / 2. The problem can be present in the second separable filter (Y-filter) but times are not so different.

Comment: CPU's have FPU's built in these days...

Comment: Yes, but the FPU's still take several machine cycles longer to perform a multiplication than the integer units do.

Comment: Repeated operations (like in your test) are ideal to exploit CPU ALU/FPU pipelining at maximum potential. This means that, excluding start and rare pipelining failures, double/integer operations are perfomed about once (or more depending on CPU) per clock. IMO, this could lead to very similar results in term of performance.

Comment: @digEmAll, then perhaps increase in no of repetitions will show decrease the difference between mean values - right? But I guess it would be difficult to prove as we may have time diff due to cache misses.

Comment: If you will post code that can be tested...may be somebody might run some tests :)

Comment: **@VinayC:** mine is a simple supposition. To predict CPU time of certain operations is extremely complicated (if not impossible) with current tremendously complex CPU architectures. Anyway what I meant was the following: **If we performed a single double/integer operation the difference between the 2 would be significant. But due to hugely optimized CPU pipelines, over a big amount of operations, the different become smaller.** And this thanks to ILP :) --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_level_parallelism

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like you are saying you are only running that inner loop 5000 times in even your longest case. The FPU last I checked (admittedly a long time ago) only took about 5 more cycles to perform a multiply than the integer unit. So by using integers you would be saving about 25,000 CPU cycles. That's assuming no cache misses or anything else that would cause the CPU to sit and wait in either event.

Assuming a modern Intel Core CPU clocked in the neighborhood of 2.5Ghz, You could expect to have saved about 10 *microseconds* runtime by using the integer unit. Kinda paltry. I do realtime programming for a living, and we wouldn't sweat that much CPU wastage here, even if we were missing a deadline somewhere.

digEmAll makes a very good point in the comments though. If the compiler and optimizer are doing their jobs, the entire thing is pipelined. That means that in actuality *the entire innner loop* will take 5 cycles longer to run with the FPU than the Integer Unit, not each operation in it. If that were the case, your expected time savings would be so small it would be tough to measure them.

If you really are doing enough floating-point ops to make the entire shebang take a very long time, I'd suggest looking into doing one or more of the following:

1. Parallelize your algorithm and run it on every CPU available from your processor.
2. Don't run it on the CLR (use native C++, or Ada or Fortran or something).
3. Rewrite it to run on the GPU. GPUs are essentially array processors and are designed to do massively parallel math on arrays of floating-point values.

Comment: Ok i simplified a bit the code. The outer loop runs on the entire image (500000 iterations for example). Then for each pixel the inner loop (no more than 25-27 iterations here, depending from the filter size) calculates the new pixel value. I think you guys are right.

Comment: Yeah, i really need to enhance the code because i need it to build a scale space (an array of images smoothed with increasing gaussians) in few time. It seems parallelization or is the only (simple to implement) viable choice

Comment: It **has** to run on the CLR then? That seemed the simplest of the three to try to me.

Comment: @T.E.D.:  .NET code is compiled at run-time to native machine code, and most operations will run more or less the same speed as direct-to-native code.  There are exceptions, such as array indexing, which is slower because it's a function call that does bounds checking.  For that reason, I recommended using pointers instead of array indexing, because I think that is actually the slowest part of his loop, according to my tests.

Comment: @P Daddy - I know how the CLR works. For most operations it is indeed not a lot slower. However, this is not "most operations", and "not a lot slower" can really add up when you do it half a million times in a tight loop. Optimizing stuff like this is the forte` of traditional native compilers like C++, Fortran, Ada, etc, so let them do what they do best, and let your C# compiler do what it does best (make everything else easier). So just move the one routine with the tight loop out of the CLR into a native project, and call it from the CLR code. If it doesn't help enough, put it back.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I gave a fairly thorough treatment of this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505162/transfer-of-control-and-data-between-c-and-c/2505358#2505358.  Of note, the cost of the P/Invoke layer may outweigh small benefits of implementing in a lower-level language.  And I really think that in this case, the benefits would be non-existent or nearly so.

Comment: It's *possible* that avoiding the CLR will speed things up, but that's far from guaranteed. In other words, try it, but measure both ways.

Answer (score 20):

Using Visual C++, because that way I can be sure that I'm timing arithmetic operations and not much else.

Results (each operation is performed 600 million times):

```
i16 add: 834575
i32 add: 840381
i64 add: 1691091
f32 add: 987181
f64 add: 979725
i16 mult: 850516
i32 mult: 858988
i64 mult: 6526342
f32 mult: 1085199
f64 mult: 1072950
i16 divide: 3505916
i32 divide: 3123804
i64 divide: 10714697
f32 divide: 8309924
f64 divide: 8266111

freq = 1562587
```

CPU is an Intel Core i7, Turbo Boosted to 2.53 GHz.

Benchmark code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

template<void (*unit)(void)>
void profile( const char* label )
{
    static __int64 cumtime;
    LARGE_INTEGER before, after;
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&before);
    (*unit)();
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&after);
    after.QuadPart -= before.QuadPart;
    printf("%s: %I64i\n", label, cumtime += after.QuadPart);
}

const unsigned repcount = 10000000;

template<typename T>
void add(volatile T& var, T val) { var += val; }

template<typename T>
void mult(volatile T& var, T val) { var *= val; }

template<typename T>
void divide(volatile T& var, T val) { var /= val; }

template<typename T, void (*fn)(volatile T& var, T val)>
void integer_op( void )
{
    unsigned reps = repcount;
    do {
        volatile T var = 2000;
        fn(var,5);
        fn(var,6);
        fn(var,7);
        fn(var,8);
        fn(var,9);
        fn(var,10);
    } while (--reps);
}

template<typename T, void (*fn)(volatile T& var, T val)>
void fp_op( void )
{
    unsigned reps = repcount;
    do {
        volatile T var = (T)2.0;
        fn(var,(T)1.01);
        fn(var,(T)1.02);
        fn(var,(T)1.03);
        fn(var,(T)2.01);
        fn(var,(T)2.02);
        fn(var,(T)2.03);
    } while (--reps);
}

int main( void )
{
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;
    unsigned reps = 10;
    do {
        profile<&integer_op<__int16,add<__int16>>>("i16 add");
        profile<&integer_op<__int32,add<__int32>>>("i32 add");
        profile<&integer_op<__int64,add<__int64>>>("i64 add");
        profile<&fp_op<float,add<float>>>("f32 add");
        profile<&fp_op<double,add<double>>>("f64 add");

        profile<&integer_op<__int16,mult<__int16>>>("i16 mult");
        profile<&integer_op<__int32,mult<__int32>>>("i32 mult");
        profile<&integer_op<__int64,mult<__int64>>>("i64 mult");
        profile<&fp_op<float,mult<float>>>("f32 mult");
        profile<&fp_op<double,mult<double>>>("f64 mult");

        profile<&integer_op<__int16,divide<__int16>>>("i16 divide");
        profile<&integer_op<__int32,divide<__int32>>>("i32 divide");
        profile<&integer_op<__int64,divide<__int64>>>("i64 divide");
        profile<&fp_op<float,divide<float>>>("f32 divide");
        profile<&fp_op<double,divide<double>>>("f64 divide");

        ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

        putchar('\n');
    } while (--reps);

    printf("freq = %I64i\n", freq);
}
```

I did a default optimized build using Visual C++ 2010 32-bit.

Every call to `profile`, `add`, `mult`, and `divide` (inside the loops) got inlined.  Function calls were still generated to `profile`, but since 60 million operations get done for each call, I think the function call overhead is unimportant.

Even with `volatile` thrown in, the Visual C++ optimizing compiler is **SMART**.  I originally used small integers as the right-hand operand, and the compiler happily used `lea` and `add` instructions to do integer multiply.  You may get more of a boost from calling out to highly optimized C++ code than the common wisdom suggests, simply because the C++ optimizer does a much better job than any JIT.

Originally I had the initialization of `var` outside the loop, and that made the floating-point multiply code run miserably slow because of the constant overflows.  FPU handling NaNs is slow, something else to keep in mind when writing high-performance number-crunching routines.

The dependencies are also set up in such a way as to prevent pipelining.  If you want to see the effects of pipelining, say so in a comment, and I'll revise the testbench to operate on multiple variables instead of just one.

Disassembly of i32 multiply:

```
;   COMDAT ??$integer_op@H$1??$mult@H@@YAXACHH@Z@@YAXXZ
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_var$66971 = -4                     ; size = 4
??$integer_op@H$1??$mult@H@@YAXACHH@Z@@YAXXZ PROC   ; integer_op<int,&mult<int> >, COMDAT

; 29   : {

  00000 55       push    ebp
  00001 8b ec        mov     ebp, esp
  00003 51       push    ecx

; 30   :    unsigned reps = repcount;

  00004 b8 80 96 98 00   mov     eax, 10000000      ; 00989680H
  00009 b9 d0 07 00 00   mov     ecx, 2000      ; 000007d0H
  0000e 8b ff        npad    2
$LL3@integer_op@5:

; 31   :    do {
; 32   :        volatile T var = 2000;

  00010 89 4d fc     mov     DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp], ecx

; 33   :        fn(var,751);

  00013 8b 55 fc     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp]
  00016 69 d2 ef 02 00
    00       imul    edx, 751       ; 000002efH
  0001c 89 55 fc     mov     DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp], edx

; 34   :        fn(var,6923);

  0001f 8b 55 fc     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp]
  00022 69 d2 0b 1b 00
    00       imul    edx, 6923      ; 00001b0bH
  00028 89 55 fc     mov     DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp], edx

; 35   :        fn(var,7124);

  0002b 8b 55 fc     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp]
  0002e 69 d2 d4 1b 00
    00       imul    edx, 7124      ; 00001bd4H
  00034 89 55 fc     mov     DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp], edx

; 36   :        fn(var,81);

  00037 8b 55 fc     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp]
  0003a 6b d2 51     imul    edx, 81            ; 00000051H
  0003d 89 55 fc     mov     DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp], edx

; 37   :        fn(var,9143);

  00040 8b 55 fc     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp]
  00043 69 d2 b7 23 00
    00       imul    edx, 9143      ; 000023b7H
  00049 89 55 fc     mov     DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp], edx

; 38   :        fn(var,101244215);

  0004c 8b 55 fc     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp]
  0004f 69 d2 37 dd 08
    06       imul    edx, 101244215     ; 0608dd37H

; 39   :    } while (--reps);

  00055 48       dec     eax
  00056 89 55 fc     mov     DWORD PTR _var$66971[ebp], edx
  00059 75 b5        jne     SHORT $LL3@integer_op@5

; 40   : }

  0005b 8b e5        mov     esp, ebp
  0005d 5d       pop     ebp
  0005e c3       ret     0
??$integer_op@H$1??$mult@H@@YAXACHH@Z@@YAXXZ ENDP   ; integer_op<int,&mult<int> >
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
_TEXT   ENDS
```

And of f64 multiply:

```
;   COMDAT ??$fp_op@N$1??$mult@N@@YAXACNN@Z@@YAXXZ
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_var$67014 = -8                     ; size = 8
??$fp_op@N$1??$mult@N@@YAXACNN@Z@@YAXXZ PROC        ; fp_op<double,&mult<double> >, COMDAT

; 44   : {

  00000 55       push    ebp
  00001 8b ec        mov     ebp, esp
  00003 83 e4 f8     and     esp, -8            ; fffffff8H

; 45   :    unsigned reps = repcount;

  00006 dd 05 00 00 00
    00       fld     QWORD PTR __real@4000000000000000
  0000c 83 ec 08     sub     esp, 8
  0000f dd 05 00 00 00
    00       fld     QWORD PTR __real@3ff028f5c28f5c29
  00015 b8 80 96 98 00   mov     eax, 10000000      ; 00989680H
  0001a dd 05 00 00 00
    00       fld     QWORD PTR __real@3ff051eb851eb852
  00020 dd 05 00 00 00
    00       fld     QWORD PTR __real@3ff07ae147ae147b
  00026 dd 05 00 00 00
    00       fld     QWORD PTR __real@4000147ae147ae14
  0002c dd 05 00 00 00
    00       fld     QWORD PTR __real@400028f5c28f5c29
  00032 dd 05 00 00 00
    00       fld     QWORD PTR __real@40003d70a3d70a3d
  00038 eb 02        jmp     SHORT $LN3@fp_op@3
$LN22@fp_op@3:

; 46   :    do {
; 47   :        volatile T var = (T)2.0;
; 48   :        fn(var,(T)1.01);
; 49   :        fn(var,(T)1.02);
; 50   :        fn(var,(T)1.03);
; 51   :        fn(var,(T)2.01);
; 52   :        fn(var,(T)2.02);
; 53   :        fn(var,(T)2.03);
; 54   :    } while (--reps);

  0003a d9 ce        fxch    ST(6)
$LN3@fp_op@3:
  0003c 48       dec     eax
  0003d d9 ce        fxch    ST(6)
  0003f dd 14 24     fst     QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  00042 dd 04 24     fld     QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  00045 d8 ce        fmul    ST(0), ST(6)
  00047 dd 1c 24     fstp    QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  0004a dd 04 24     fld     QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  0004d d8 cd        fmul    ST(0), ST(5)
  0004f dd 1c 24     fstp    QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  00052 dd 04 24     fld     QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  00055 d8 cc        fmul    ST(0), ST(4)
  00057 dd 1c 24     fstp    QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  0005a dd 04 24     fld     QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  0005d d8 cb        fmul    ST(0), ST(3)
  0005f dd 1c 24     fstp    QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  00062 dd 04 24     fld     QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  00065 d8 ca        fmul    ST(0), ST(2)
  00067 dd 1c 24     fstp    QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  0006a dd 04 24     fld     QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  0006d d8 cf        fmul    ST(0), ST(7)
  0006f dd 1c 24     fstp    QWORD PTR _var$67014[esp+8]
  00072 75 c6        jne     SHORT $LN22@fp_op@3
  00074 dd d8        fstp    ST(0)
  00076 dd dc        fstp    ST(4)
  00078 dd da        fstp    ST(2)
  0007a dd d8        fstp    ST(0)
  0007c dd d8        fstp    ST(0)
  0007e dd d8        fstp    ST(0)
  00080 dd d8        fstp    ST(0)

; 55   : }

  00082 8b e5        mov     esp, ebp
  00084 5d       pop     ebp
  00085 c3       ret     0
??$fp_op@N$1??$mult@N@@YAXACNN@Z@@YAXXZ ENDP        ; fp_op<double,&mult<double> >
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
_TEXT   ENDS
```

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm seems to access large regions of memory in a very non-sequential pattern.  It's probably generating tons of cache misses.  The bottleneck is probably memory access, not arithmetic.  Using ints should make this slightly faster because ints are 32 bits, while doubles are 64 bits, meaning cache will be used slightly more efficiently.  If almost every loop iteration involves a cache miss, though, you're basically out of luck unless you can make some algorithmic or data structure layout changes to improve the locality of reference.

BTW, have you considered using an FFT for convolution?  That would put you in a completely different big-O class.

Comment: Can you explain me why do you think i have many cache-miss? I'm using a linear "index" that iterate through adjacent memory cells. Also the "filterOffstetsX" contains small offsets relatives to pixels on the same row and at a max distance of filter size / 2.

Comment: I think FFT does not suites very well for my problem (building a pyramid of incrementally convolved images). I do not have a single big convolution but an iteration of convolutions with small to medium filters. If i figure how to apply FFT in a incremental fashion then it could be useful..

Comment: The cache miss problem however may be present in the Y-filtering part of the separable convolution. But this does not seem to affect very much performance (i have similar times both from X and Y filtering)

Answer (score 2):

at least it is not fair to compare `int` (DWORD, 4 bytes) and `double` (QWORD, 8 bytes) on 32-bit system. Compare `int` to `float` or `long` to `double` to get fair results. `double` has increased precision, you must pay for it.

**PS**: for me it smells like micro(+premature) optimization, and that smell is not good.

**Edit**: Ok, good point. It is not correct to compare long to double, but still comparing int and double on 32 CPU is not correct even if they have both intrinsic instructions. This is not magic, x86 is fat CISC, still double is not processed as single step internally.

Comment: The code is optimized and works very well. However the original version only accepts double images. Introducing ints i expected to have a gain thanks to 32 bit integer operations.

Comment: comparing long to double isn't fair either - IIRC, an x86 CPU has arithmetic instructions for double precision floats, but not for 64 bit integers.

Comment: @nikie that's true, but still comparing int and double on 32 CPU is not correct even if they have both intrinsic instructions. This is not magic, x86 is fat CISC, still double is not processed as single step internally.

Comment: Actually, it is fair to compare 4 byte int ops against 8 byte floating point ops in some cases.  The C compiler may cast floats to doubles to do arithmetic and then back again to float. Floating point hardware usually has the ability to work on 8 byte floats natively.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, I find that floating-point multiplication is about the same speed as integer multiplication.

I'm using this timing function:

```
static void Time<T>(int count, string desc, Func<T> action){
    action();

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        action();

    double seconds = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} took {1} seconds", desc, seconds);
}
```

Let's say you're processing a 200 x 200 array with a 25-length filter 200 times, then your inner loop is executing 200 * 200 * 25 * 200 = 200,000,000 times.  Each time, you're doing one multiply, one add, and **3** array indices.  So I use this profiling code

```
const int count = 200000000;

int[]  a = {1};
double d = 5;
int    i = 5;

Time(count, "array index", ()=>a[0]);
Time(count, "double mult", ()=>d * 6);
Time(count, "double add ", ()=>d + 6);
Time(count, "int    mult", ()=>i * 6);
Time(count, "int    add ", ()=>i + 6);
```

On my machine (slower than yours, I think), I get the following results:

```
array index took 1.4076632 seconds
double mult took 1.2203911 seconds
double add  took 1.2342998 seconds
int    mult took 1.2170384 seconds
int    add  took 1.0945793 seconds
```

As you see, integer multiplication, floating-point multiplication, and floating-point addition all took about the same time.  Array indexing took a little longer (and you're doing it three times), and integer addition was a little faster.

So I think the performance advantage to integer math in your scenario is just too slight to make a significant difference, especially when outweighed by the relatively huge penalty you're paying for array indexing.  If you really need to speed this up, then you should use unsafe pointers to your arrays to avoid the offset calculation and bounds checking.

By the way, the performance difference for division is much more striking.  Following the pattern above, I get:

```
double div  took 3.8597251 seconds
int    div  took 1.7824505 seconds
```

---

One more note:

Just to be clear, all profiling should be done with an optimized release build.  Debug builds will be slower overall, and some operations may not have accurate timing with respect to others.

Comment: Try the same algorithim with either `float` or `_int64`, so you aren't timing differences due to the sheer amount of data being moved around.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I don't think that's necessary.  For one, I'm not really moving data around, since I'm performing the operation on the same datum repeatedly, I should be staying in L1 cache the whole time.  So I'm pretty much timing just the operation itself.  For two, I'm already showing that floating-point multiply is about the same speed as integer multiply.  There's really no need to prove it further.  By the way, there is no `_int64` type in C# (or in any other language, for that matter.  The non-standard MSVC extension is `__int64`, with two underscores).  In C#, `long` is 64-bits.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was just looking at the division numbers, and was thinking the 2x might have something to do w/ the data being twice as much, but I see now from the numbers above that is not the case. I do remember from my school days (reading about the brand-spanking new "Pentium" chip) that floating-point division took by far more cycles than anything else. That's why a lot of folks try to rejigger all FP math as multiplies (by reciprocating one of the arguments outside of the tight loop).

Comment: Your times feel too high by a factor of 10-12, assuming a 2 GHz processor, since no modern desktop CPU takes multiple cycles for a 32-bit integer add.  Did you check the generated machine code and make sure that the lambda got inlined?  In fact, since the lambda provably has no side effect, all of the operations you are trying to test probably got optimized away, and all you're measuring is a delegate call (basically, call made through a function pointer at the native level).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: **Your assumptions are worthless:** I didn't use a 2 GHz CPU.  **Your logic is faulty:** the result will never be `count * number_of_CPU_cycles_for_ADD_instruction`—at a minimum you must also consider the instructions comprising the loop itself, the timings of which I didn't deduct.  **And you're not paying attention:** the exact timings are irrelevant—the point was to compare the *relative* timings of the different candidate operations for the OP's problem.  I would appreciate in the future not being downvoted based on worthless assumptions, faulty logic, and improper focus.

Comment: @P Daddy: Your comment applies exactly to your answer.  You haven't looked at the machine code generated by the JIT to see if the operations you are trying to test are even there, nevermind whether an integer division by a constant got converted to magic number multiplication.  I still claim, **you are not measuring what you think you are**.  You need to set up a test where the overhead is not 10 times larger than what you are trying to measure.  That's all the 2GHz assumption was used for, to get a rough idea of how much overhead you're paying.

Comment: @P: Unless your processor is <= 300 MHz, the conclusion I got from the 2GHz assumption is still valid (the operation you wanted to measure is insignificant compared to the overhead).  You're not measuring relative timings, because the ratio of `(x + overhead) / (y + overhead)` is not the same ratio as `x / y` (that's what relative means btw).  At best you can say which is faster, and only if the overhead is highly consistent (it's not), but your claim of "about the same speed" falls flat.

Comment: @P: For example, if the overhead (which you haven't even attempted to isolate) is 1.08s, then double add takes almost 11 times as long as integer add.  **You must isolate what you are measuring from the overhead, in order to make any statement about how much faster one is than the other**.  Finally, your reported times have too many significant digits to the point where it's ridiculous.  Are those times reproducible?  No, I thought not.

Comment: @P: In fact, the only thing you've proven is that the .NET JIT compiler fails miserably at optimization.  The whole loop provably has no side effects and would have been removed by any decent optimizer.  I think you're running up against the heuristic that prevents inlining of methods which are long in terms of IL, even though they could compile down to nothing.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Now you're just being obstinate.  And you're making poor assumptions again.  The results **are** reproducible.  Try it yourself.  The exact ratio of times here is not important.  The fact is, the wall time difference between 200 million floating-point additions or multiplications or the same number of integer operations is insignificant.

Comment: @P: If it's even doing the additions and multiplications, which the optimizer could and should be removing, since you don't use the results anywhere.  Show some disassembly of the code produced by the JIT, and then we can get some feel for what you really measured.  As for try it myself, I have done so and am ready to post my code, disassembly, and timing momentarily.

Comment: BTW, optimized x86 code for `i * 6` doesn't even use the `imul` instruction.  You **need** to look at *disassembly*.

Answer (score 0):

If the times you measuerd are accurate, then the runtime of your filtering algorithm seems to grow with the cube of the filter size. What kind of filter is that? Maybe you can reduce the number of multiplications needed. (e.g. if you're using a separable filter kernel?)

Otherwise, if you need raw performance, you might consider using a library like the Intel Performance Primitives - it contains highly optimized functions for things like this that use CPU SIMD instructions. They're usually a lot faster than hand-written code in C# or C++.

Comment: i'm using a gaussian separable kernel of increasing size (i'm calculating a scale-space, it is a very time-consuming process).    Do IPP works in .NET?

Comment: @Marco: Applying a gaussian filter with size k to an image should be an O(k) operation, but the times you posted didn't look like O(k). Maybe you should check your algorithm. That said, yes, you can use IPP from C# using P/Invoke. Or you can use a .NET wrapper for OpenCV (OpenCV uses the IPP automatically if it's available)

Comment: Well the code i posted is 1D filter, but this is only half the original 2D filter. The filter is applied along 2 dimensions, so total complexity shold be 2*k*m*n (m*m = image size)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at the disassembled code? In high-level languages i'm pretty much trusting the compiler to optimize my code.
For example `for(i=0;i<imageSize;i++)` might be faster than `foreach`.
Also, arithmetic operrations might get optimized by the compiler anyway.... when you need to optimize something you either optimize the whole "black-box" and maybe reinvent the algorithm used in that loop, or you first take a look at the dissasembled code and see whats wrong with it