# C# Improving CPU Speed in Division, by specifying # of Decimal Places

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, operators

This is about optimizing CPU speed. I'm looking for nanosecond gains.

Basic setup:

```
double Result;
Result = (double) 1 / 3;
```

This gives "0.333333333333333". What I'm looking for is only 4 significant decimal places without doing the entire division. So, rounding after the division makes no difference. The CPU should stop working on the problem the moment he has arrived at the 4th decimal place.

Is this an improvement?

```
int Num = (int) 1 * 10000 / 3;
double Result = Num / (double) 10000;
```

or simply

```
double Result = (int)(1*10000/3)/(double)10000
```

Is this faster? even with the additional multiplication by 10000?

I was hoping the Math method had something like Math.Divide(numerator,denominator,significantDecimalPlaces). Any recommendations?

Comment: It doesn't "cost extra" for the CPU to compute the extra bits (within the same fixed type).. rounding is a separate issue and should be done if/as needed as it changes the result. [Does C# Compiler calculate math on constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752559/does-c-sharp-compiler-calculate-math-on-constants) is interesting reading, and may be relevant.

Comment: (Also, at the end of day this class of "optimization" will probably not be relevant. In the rare cases when such may matter - and the code probably won't be in C# - it should be shown to be a performance hotspot.)

Comment: for integer division, see : http://libdivide.com/  - it's c++, but you can import into C#.  As has been said, however, it's rather worth profiling to find your hotspots.  If division really is the problem there may be other ways of optimizing.  Without knowing what you are doing, it is hard to suggest...

Comment: @user2864740 especially for compile time constant as shown in sample  :). Standard recommendation as requested: [horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPUs do not calculate digits of result sequentally. Also, CPU operate with binary numbers, not with decimal numbers as mere mortals do.
Anyway, programmers cannot mess with their internals: these algorithms are physically built into the hardware.
So you cannot "partially do" an instruction.

There are several low-precision instructions in SSE which work much faster than their fully precise equivalents: namely, reciprocal and rsqrt. But they are only two exceptions to the general rule. In general, there are no low-precision equivalents for almost all instructions.

Indeed, multiplications are significantly faster than divisions on modern CPUs. So if the denominator does not change across divisions, you should precalculate its reciprocal (i.e. inverse), then multiply all the numerators by it. Consider vector normalization as an example:

```cpp
double x, y, z;  //input vector
double invLen = 1.0 / sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
x *= invLen;  y *= invLen;  z *= invLen;
```

C++ compilers usually do not perform such optimization because `a / b` and `a * (1/b)` may be slightly different according to IEEE rules of floating point arithmetic. But if you turn on *fast math* switch, they will do it. I'm not sure how C# compiler behaves by default. Also, compilers easily replace division by compile-time constant integer number with multiplication.

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for. Also, by chance I have that exact setup...changing variable with a constant divisor. So, thank you for expanding the answer.

Previously, I relied mostly on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676567/integer-vs-double-arithmetic-performance) . But this clarified it.